# How to get the path to the directory of the opened file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I'm Kenyon Bowers.
I have some code that opens a open file dialog. It opens .DSCProj (which are specific to my project), and I am going to run some terminal commands in the directory that the opened file is in.
I have no idea how to do that.

preload.ts:

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from "electron";
import { dialog } from '@electron/remote'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    showOpenFileDialog: () => dialog.showOpenDialogSync({
        properties: ["openFile"],
        filters: [
            {
                name: "DSC Projects",
                extensions: ["DSCProj"],
            },
        ],
    })
});
```

NewProject.ts:

```
declare var api: any;

function OpenProject(): void {
  const file = api.showOpenFileDialog();
  console.log("Done")
  if(file != null){
    localStorage.setItem('DirPath', file);
    location.href='./views/projectOpen.html'
  }
}



(() => {
  document.querySelector('#btn-open-project')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    OpenProject();
  }),
  document.querySelector('#btn-new-project')?.addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.href='./views/projectNew.html'
  })
})()
```

As you can see on line 7, I'm setting local storage to the file's path. But I need to set it to the path of the directory that the file is in.

Comment: So Electron's `dialog.showOpenDialog()` return a promise and thus, would need to be handled accordingly. Can you confirm within your `NewProject.ts` file that adding the code `console.log(file)` immediately after line 4 returns something similar to `Promise {pending}`? If not, we will need to address the return of the promise within your `preload.ts` script. PS: I don't use typescript and my `preload` script(s) do not contain direct implementations.

Comment: even when putting the console.log(file); it logs the path to the file. It does not say Promise {pending}...

Comment: Ok, so you are receiving the path to the selected file. Great.  Now, just to confirm, you want to remove the file name (and extension) from the file path so that all you are left with only the folder(s) path preceding the file name. Correct?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst use of [@electron/remote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote) is great and all, you may be better served by implementing certain Electron modules within the main thread instead of the render thread(s). This is primarily for security but as a strong second reason, it keeps your code separated. IE: Separation of concerns.

Unlike vanilla Javascript, [node.js](https://nodejs.org) has a simple function [path.parse(path).dir](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/path.html#pathparsepath) to easily remove the file name (and extension) from the file path without needing to worry about which OS (IE: Directory separator) you are using. This would also be implemented within your main thread. Implementing something like this within your render thread would take a lot more work with vanilla Javascript to be OS proof.

Lastly, in the code below I will use a `preload.js` script that only deals with the movement of messages and their data between the main thread and render thread(s). I do not believe that the concrete implementation of functions in your `preload.js` script(s) is the right approach (though others may argue).

> Note: I am not using typescript in the below code, but you should get the general idea.

---

Let's use the channel name `getPath` within the `invoke` method.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'getPath'
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Now, in the main thread, let's listen for a call on the `getPath` channel. When called, open up the [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) and upon the return of a path, process it with Node's [path.parse(path).dir](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/path.html#pathparsepath) function to remove the file name (and extension). Lastly, return the modified path.

`main.js` (main thread)

```jsconst
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronDialog = require('electron').dialog;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// -----

// Let's listen for a call on the 'getPath' channel
electronIpcMain.handle('getPath', async () => {
    // Dialog options.
    const options = {
        properties: ["openFile"],
        filters: [
            {
                name: "DSC Projects",
                extensions: ["DSCProj"],
            }
        ]
    }

    // When available, return the modified path back to the render thread via IPC
    return await openDialog(window, options)
        .then((result) => {
            // User cancelled the dialog
            if (result.canceled === true) { return; }

            // Modify and return the path
            let path = result.filePaths[0];
            let modifiedPath = nodePath.parse(path).dir; // Here's the magic.
            console.log(modifiedPath); // Testing

            return modifiedPath;
        })
})

// Create an open dialog
function openDialog(parentWindow, options) {
    return electronDialog.showOpenDialog(parentWindow, options)
        .then((result) => { if (result) { return result; } })
        .catch((error) => { console.error('Show open dialog error: ' + error); });
}
```

---

Here you will get the general idea about how to use the returned result.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Open Project Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btn-open-project" value="Open Project">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('btn-open-project').addEventListener('click', () => {
            openProject();
         });

        function openProject() {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('getPath')
                .then((path) => {
                    // As we are using "invoke" a response will be returned, even if undefined.
                    if (path === undefined) { return; } // When user cancels dialog.

                    console.log(path); // Testing.
                    // window.localStorage.setItem('DirPath', path);
                    // location.href='./views/projectOpen.html';
                });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't know if this is related to this or if I should ask a new question but, how would I save the modifiedPath into the localStorage?

Comment: Modifying your current line to `window.localStorage.setItem('DirPath', path);` should do the trick. That said, the behaviour of using local storage on a locally server file (IE: `file:`) is "undefined". See [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for more information. If this option is unstable, you could save information in a `.json` file at the users application data directory. See [app.getPath('userData')](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) for more information.

Comment: Another good, easy to understand source of localStorage information is at [LogRocket - localStorage in Javascript: A complete guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/).

Comment: Updated answer to reflect addition of `window` in `window.localStorage.setItem('DirPath', path);`.